# C programming find output for C89?

Tags: c

What is the value of each of the following expressions in C89 ? ( Give all possible values if an expression may have more than one value.)

```
a) 8/5 
My answer 1

b) -8/5 
A : -1

c)8/-5

A: -1

d)-8/-5
A:1

e)8 % -5
Answer: output is 3 but why? 
Also,are the other answers correct?
```

Comment: @MitchWheat could not, as it is implementation defined.

Comment: *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved* I vote for reopen as most C programmers are actually not aware most of these expression values are implementation defined.

Answer (score 6):

The results of b), c) and e) are implementation-defined as integer division rounding direction with negative operand is implementation-defined in c89. In c99 the rounding is towards zero but in c89 it is implementation-defined.

For example:

```
-8/5
```

result could be `-1` (truncation towards zero) or `-2` (truncation towards minus infinity).

Same for `8 / -5`.

`8 % -5` result can `3` (truncation towards zero)  or `-2` (truncation towards minus infinity).